# Error in Android Environment Setup

Tags: android, android-settings

Recently i have made a `check for update`. then ADT version look like
[image]

my SDK version look
[image]

But i still get an error while creating a new project target compile version not there
[image]

Comment: you need to check android sdk Location  in  your preferences again

Comment: fully check you have latest version of ADT.....sometimes it makes error

Answer (score 0):

it means that there is no such theme in your Android SDK. just go to xml files, and remove declarations of those themes after you create the project

Comment: there is no option for compile with also.

Comment: umm, is it required to select something there?